# Template URL renders parameters in wrong order and it creates NoReverseMatch error. Why it is happening?

Tags: python, django

I am getting  NoReverseMatch

```
>     Reverse for 'production_order_new' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'quantity': Decimal('444.000'), u'uri':
> 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/production/soproduct/list/', u'pk_bom': 2,
> u'pk_soproduct': 1}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
> ['production/production/order/new/(?P<pk_bom>\\d+)/(?P<pk_soproduct>\\d+)/(?P<uri>\\S+)/(?P<quantity>\\d+(\\.\\d{1,2,3}))/$']
```

My url file

```
      url(r'^production/order/new/(?P<pk_bom>\d+)/
(?P<pk_soproduct>\d+)/(?P<uri>\S+)/(?P<quantity>\d+(\.\d{1,2,3}))/$', 
views.Production_order_new, name="production_order_new"),
```

and my link in the template

```
      <a href="
          {% url 'production_order_new' pk_bom=bom.id 
pk_soproduct=soproduct.id  uri=request.build_absolute_uri quantity=bom.quantity %}
          ">PO material</a>
```

translates to

```
'{u'quantity': Decimal('444.000'), u'uri':
 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/production/soproduct/list/', u'pk_bom': 2,
 u'pk_soproduct': 1}'
```

For some reason it messes the order i believe this is the reason for NoReverseMatch . What is the reason and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url should be corrected as:

```
url(r'^production/order/new/(?P<pk_bom>\d+)/(?P<pk_soproduct>\d+)/(?P<uri>\S+)/(?P<quantity>\d+(\.\d{1,3}))/$',
     views.Production_order_new, name="production_order_new"),
```